# What is the problem with this question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701704/where-can-i-see-sample-codes-of-downloading-and-complex-object-and-storing-it-in

And why do I get a moderator message for being rude? In what way I am being rude? I am not the only one asking for sample codes for common problems.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sample+code

What's the difference between that particular question and all other questions ?

Comment: Thats really **not a question**

Comment: I am asking for some code sample. Where can I find those? I think I asked similar questions before. What I am missing. I am really missing what the problem is. I am not trying to be sarcastic or anything.

Comment: Maybe I should add a few code samples of what I am currently doing. Looks to me all stackoverflow questions need to contain code.

Comment: yes, that is nice way to ask, otherwise someone will only think that you want readymade code, and you haven't done any searching for it.

Comment: So that's the issue. I see. I see.

Comment: No, questions don't `have` to include code. Questions `DO` need to ask a clear question that is not just "give me the code". Why, for instance, did the links to informational videos not solve your problem? The fact that you insist on being provided with pre-written code looks fishy.

Comment: Because it's a very common problem and I've searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution. My own solution is fishy.

Comment: Edit your question to ask for approach rather than code.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment thread of the question, Stack Overflow does not exist to spit out code snippets for you. [Try something](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Put forth something that resembles effort. Or hire a competent developer to write the code for you.

Comment: I already tried something and will post that. Yea approach would be better. Thanks for all the suggestion.

Comment: Look if asking for sample code is off topic then just say so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sample+code

Comment: @JimThio - Pointing out that other people are also asking questions equivalent to "gimmeh teh codez, plz" is irrelevant. Again, **it is not our job to vomit out code snippets for you**. Hire a competent developer.

Comment: I am asking a question what's the difference between all those questions asking for sample code from my question. That is a very SIMPLE question. Why keep circumventing.

Comment: @JimThio - Again, **the fact that other people have begged for code snippets is utterly and completely irrelevant**. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701704/what-would-be-a-better-good-approach-of-downloading-and-complex-object-and-stori) remains unacceptable in SO. Period. End of story. End of debate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Where can I see sample codes of downloading and complex object and storing it into core data efficiently?

Because a question asking for code samples is not acceptable here.

In general, Stack Overflow questions should not have answers where there is no *objective* criteria for deciding if it is correct or not. If I answer a question, I should have the right to know that my answer is actually answering the question, not *guessing* at an answer. If the only person who can decide if an answer is right is the OP, then it's probably not a good question.

In your case, you just want some random ObjectiveC code about dealing with "complex object"s. Who's to say that one bit of such code is any better than another? It would be nothing more than a popularity contest between various different schemes for such things.

That's not what Stack Overflow is for. I shouldn't have to guess if a particular answer is "complex" enough for you, or shows off exactly what you need or whatever.

> Look if asking for sample code is off topic then just say so.

It's not a matter of on-topic vs. off-topic. It's a matter of what is *appropriate* for what we do here. And your question is not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sample+code there are many others that also ask for sample codes. The criteria is simply efficient (not going to the permanent store too often, with prefetching.

Comment: @Jim: Questions from 2010 are old. Once upon a time, we tolerated garbage questions like that. We're more strict about question standards than we used to be. If you look at more recent stuff, you'll see more downvoting of such questions. Also, old questions with downvotes and no answers generally are culled by the system, so looking into the history will only show the ones that were tolerated, not eliminated.

Comment: I see. That is A GOOD answer to my question. That's it. That's all I ask.

Comment: And I have found the answer to the question. I updated the question. It's actually a very easy question for those who are knowledgeable.

Comment: @JimThio - In its original state, it was not an easy question, even for those experienced with the topic. I work with Core Data all the time (I even taught a class on it) and I couldn't follow what you were asking in your original version. Only after you had edited for clarity and provided the sample code that you did was I able to understand your problem. It wasn't a matter of domain expertise, but one of how the problem was presented.

Comment: I deleted the original question already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172413/is-a-persistent-store-a-requirement-for-core-data-on-the-iphone solve my problem perfectly by the way :D LOL